# Neo4j doesn't look for multiple starting points if one of them is null

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the following scenario, node "x" does not exist.

```
start x=node:node_auto_index(key="x"), y=node(*)
return count(x), count(y)
```

It seems that if any of the starting points can't be found, nothing is returned.

Any suggestions how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is like saying the below (in SQL)--what do you expect will happen if table X is empty?

```
select count(x), count(y) 
from x, y
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to query here, but you might need to get your counts one at a time, if there's a chance that x will come back with no results:

```
start x=node:node_auto_index(key="x")
with count(x) as cntx
start y=node(*)
return cntx, count(y) as cnty
```

Comment: I'm trying to bundle a couple of things in as few statements as possible. Here's a larger snippet:
start x=node:some_index(key="x"), y=node:some_index(key="y")
with count(x) as x, y
where x=0
create x, y-[:rome_r]->x

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wes, I figured out how to do a "conditional add" with the old Cypher syntax (pre 2.0):

```
START x=node:node_auto_index(key="x")
with count(x) as exists
start y=node:node_auto_index(key="y")
where exists = 0
create (n {key:"y"})<-[:rel]-y
return n, y
```

The crux here is that you can't fire another "start" after a "where" clause. You need to query for the second node before checking for conditions (which is kind of bad for performance). This is remedied in 2.0 with if-then-else statements anyway...

Comment: You might want to check out CREATE UNIQUE also. Some of these cases it handles pretty well. `START y=node:node_auto_index(key="y") CREATE UNIQUE y-[:rel]->(n {key:"x"}) RETURN n, y`

Comment: Yup. But it ALWAYS creates the second node along. That's not what we want here. I don't want a new "y" node very time I call it :)

Comment: Yes it does. Run your example, then switch "NEW1" or something and you'll get a second "TEST" node ;)

Comment: Right, but that's not unique... and if you run NEW1 twice, you only get a new node the first time.

Comment: I suppose if you don't know what the relation will be, CREATE UNIQUE can't help you. Sometimes it does, though.

Comment: Jup, but that's not what I claimed, right? I said "it ALWAYS creates the second node along". That's my issue here. You have to retrieve both nodes before running "create unique", so it doesn't create unwanted nodes just because the relationship is missing.

Comment: Btw, IF-THEN-ELSE (or case/when) statements in 2.0 aren't going to fix this, either, unfortunately. They're only for `where` predicates and `with/return` massaging. You can't do `create` in case/when. :(

Comment: f***. Well, I hope they'll make merge work at some point. That'll do as well :)

Comment: For now you have to prepend "cypher 2.0 " to your `merge` statement (so you can use it without `start`). The 2.0 parser isn't the default. It should be fixed soon.

Comment: Oh god... I was totally unaware of that and kept wondering, why half of the new cypher syntax doesn't work with M02.